# Lie bracket of vector fields in Penrose's abstract index notation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

In the [abstract index notation of Penrose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation), indicies serve as placeholders to indicate the type of a tensor field. For example, $X^i$ denotes a vector field. What is the commonly accepted notation for the Lie bracket of two vector fields $X^i$ and $Y^j$?
Clearly, $[X^i, Y^j]^k$ does not work, because this would denote a $3$-contravariant tensor. Something like $[ \cdot, \cdot]_{ij}^{\ \ k} X^i Y^j$ would work but looks strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Penrose-Rindler write it $X^i\nabla_iY^j-Y^i\nabla_iX^j$.

Comment: Well, actually, I wanted to write the (usual) definition of the torsion tensor using indicies ;-). But thanks anyway.

Comment: @TobiasDiez You can! Above is their formula (4.3.1) which assumes $\nabla$ torsion-free (e.g. $\nabla_i=\partial_i$). In general, their (4.3.29) defines another $\tilde\nabla$’s torsion $T$ by $$[X,Y]^j=X^i\tilde\nabla_iY^j-Y^i\tilde\nabla_iX^j+T_{ik}^jX^iY^k.$$

Answer (score 3):

I think it is standard in the mathematical physics literature to write this as $[X,Y]^k$. The entire expression "$[X,Y]$" is a new vector and $k$ is its index.